# Expressing future-related well wishes on a certain occasion

Tags: phrase-request

If a company, with which my company has long been in cooperation, is celebrating its 20th birthday, what is the correct way of expressing my well wishes for them on the occasion of that anniversary?

> 1. Best wishes of constant success and progress **for 20 years
>    anniversary!**
>
> or
>
> 2. Best wishes of constant success and progress **for 20-year
>    anniversary!**
>
> or
>
> 3. Best wishes of constant success and progress **on the 20-year
>    anniversary!**
>
> or
>
> 4. Best wishes of constant success and progress **on the 20-years
>    anniversary!**
>
> or
>
> 5. ?

Will any of these not sound as if I were wishing success and progress for only that one day?

Should it be "20-year**s** anniversary" or "20-year anniversary"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are going to be some regional preferences. In the UK (this is an English question after all!) I would expect to see something like:

```
Congratulations on your 20 year anniversary and best wishes for your continued success.
```

This separates out the event (the 20 year aniversary) as the occasion which is prompting the message and the ongoing (continued) success for the future.

I think you should say **20 year anniversary** (20 years anniversay sounds odd to a British speaker).

Comment: Thank you very much. But I need to stick to the original length of the phrase as much as possible. Do you think just replacing "for" with "on" can also separate out the occasion and the ongoing success? Also, I can't use "your" because it is a congratulation note for the whole company.

Comment: "On your" would be better than just "on" - and you definitely can use your to congratulate a whole company as you can be singular or plural and in the plural context it's clear it relates to the whole company.

Comment: Can I use "on the" instead of "on your"? And what about changing "for" to "on" instead of re-phrasing?

Comment: *In my opinion* you need to use "on your" - if length is a problem you could say "Best wishes for continued success on your 20 year anniversary"